# How to understand expression lists in Python

Tags: python, list

When I read the Python document today, I found `Expression lists` on [Python Documents](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists), the description on the site like this:

> `expression_list ::=  expression ( "," expression )* [","]`
>
> *An expression list containing at least one comma yields a tuple. The length of the tuple is the number of expressions in the list. The expressions are evaluated from left to right.*
>
> *The trailing comma is required only to create a single tuple (a.k.a. a singleton); it is optional in all other cases. A single expression without a trailing comma doesn’t create a tuple, but rather yields the value of that expression. (To create an empty tuple, use an empty pair of parentheses: ().)*

Because the examples are not given on the site, So I just wondering anyone can give a brief description about this, and give a example about its usage. Thank a lots.

Comment: The language reference is not meant to be used as a "tutorial" style description of the language, it's meant to specify the language. For examples you should probably read the tutorial instead - and for most people it's the tutorial one should read first. After reading the tutorial the language reference would become more clearer.

Comment: This specifies the language, it doesn't teach you how to make lists. It's python documentation, not "Python Documents". It's "Thanks a lot", not "Thank a lot".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some samples to help you understand what is going on:

> An expression list containing at least one comma yields a tuple.

This means, that if you have `1,2`, this will create a tuple. The length is how many items you have.

> The trailing comma is required only to create a single tuple (a.k.a. a
>   singleton); it is optional in all other cases.

This means that if you want to create a tuple with one item, you need to have a comma at the end, like this `1,`, otherwise:

> A single expression without a trailing comma doesn’t create a tuple,
>   but rather yields the value of that expression.

So `1` is not creating a tuple, what will happen is the express will be evaluated. This sounds like an obvious point but it makes sense if you write `(1)` and then expect it to be evaluated as a tupe (in the case of `(1)`, it will be evaluated to the integer value `1`).

Finally

> (To create an empty tuple, use an empty pair of parentheses: ().)

If for some reason you want to create an empty tuple as an expression, use the following special syntax `()`

It is a common practice to surround expressions (especially in the case of tuples) with (), but this is not required - although sometimes it helps with readability.  `1,2` and `(1,2)` are equal:

```
>>> a = 1,2
>>> type(a)
<type 'tuple'>

>>> b = (1,2)
>>> type(b)
<type 'tuple'>

>>> a == b
True
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I have know that, but why the documents wrote `expression_list ::=  expression ( "," expression )* [","]` on it?. I just can not understand what is it mean. Is it a regular expression？

Comment: Oh, no that's just the syntax of the expression itself. It is describing how to parse the expression list (ie, what it would look like to a token parser).

Comment: Note that the expression list does not include the paretheses, consequently your examples in the beginning is a bit misleading. They should be `1, 2`, `1,` and 1 if they're to be expression lists.

Comment: @AlexanderYau it's a regular grammar. You're looking in the wrong place buddy, that page is for people who want to make a new python interpreter, not to write code. Search "tuple" or "list" instead in the search bar on python docs.

Answer (score 5):

This talks about how you write tuples.

For instance,

```
>>> 1, 2
(1, 2)
```

is a two element tuple, as is

```
>>> 7*8, 5-6
(56, -1)
```

Tuples are usually written with parentheses around them for clarity, but they are unnecessary; except in case of the 0-element tuple, `()`.

One-element tuples are another exception, as there it is mandatory to have the comma:

```
>>> 1,
(1, )
```

Without the comma it wouldn't be possible to distinguish this from the normal number `1`. You can add an extra comma after multi-element tuples too, but it doesn't do anything in that case:

```
>>> 1, 2,
(1, 2)
```